# Matching string that contains "{}". What is the correct way?

Tags: java, regex

I have already tried

```
Pattern.compile(".*\\{[}]");
```

and

```
 Pattern.compile(".*\\{}");
```

Examples of matched strings: "abc{}", "ab{}cd"
Examples of unmatched strings: "abc{", "ab{c}d"

Which is the correct way of doing that? Is there a better way?

Comment: try `str.matches(".*\\{\\}.*");`

Comment: Your regexes are the same. The first one has a character class that contains a single character, which is `}`, the second one has it without the character class `}`.

Comment: Ok.That clears one doubt. So I could use any of the regexes above. Thanks @MarounMaroun

Comment: second doubt - In what case would my regex fail ? Or both ways are correct ?

Comment: @Crusaderpyro Depends on whether you call `matches()` or `find()`. With `find()`, you can remove the `.*`, but in that case a simple `String.indexOf("{}")` would work too. With `matches()`, you need another `.*` at the end, or "ab{}cd" will not match.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. That clears all the doubts. Anyway, I was going to use find(), so ended up using .contains() method as that is a better option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid using regexes for this purpose. You can use [`String.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
if(myString.contains("{}")) {
    // your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Way better, simpler than regex !

Comment: Plus 1000 for not using a regular expression

Comment: Guys.. while this solution is correct and good (in this specific case it's really better than regex), but in general, don't be afraid of regex, they're not bad.. don't hurt their feelings. So being that happy that the solution doesn't use regex is a little bit insulting :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun - I just had to rewrite some *regex* code as it was taking too much time :P

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think those comments came because regexes are generally slower than plain search! If they are needed, don't be afraid to use them, if you can do the same thing in a simpler way without regexes, do it without them! :)

Comment: Of course they have their place, but in this instance, and others (numeric range validation) they certainly don't.

Comment: Regexes are not slow if you don't over complicate them, most (basic) regexes are O(n). In this specific case, I won't be surprised if the performances are the same.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I love regex because they are very very powerful. But here, it's like driving a Ferrari in a parking lot for 20 meters whereas I could have use my bare feet

Comment: @Thomas well.. I don't mind just sitting in a Ferrari without even moving ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun ... Ok ... You won this one... :)

Comment: Sad thing about a Ferrari is when you can finally afford one, you're all grown up with a young toddler and can therefore no longer justify it. Porsche Cayenne time. That's a bit like the regex. You just grow out of them when you realise there are better techniques.

Comment: Guys, you all made my day.

Comment: I think I am gonna hurt their feelings. Probably just end up using the contains method ! 

#scaredOfRegex

Comment: @Crusaderpyro - side note, you could use `indexOf()` as well

Answer (score 2):

```
.*[{][^}]*[}]?.*
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: In what case would my regex fail ? Or both ways are correct ?

Comment: @Crusaderpyro it would fail when there is no {